# Updating document in MarkLogic

Tags: xml, marklogic

am newbie to ML and would like to know how to
update XML document with keeping old data's canonical part.

What I would like to achieve is, after adding a canonical part,
and want to update and replace only original data part.
Since we are using same URI, canonical part disappears if I do an update.
Is there any merging option or way to do?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you mean with canonical? Are you referring to what we call the Envelope pattern within MarkLogic?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post examples of the XML inputs (prior toe the update) and outputs (desired final state) to demonstrate what the desired result is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [xdmp:node-replace](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:node-replace).  If /mydoc.xml is

```
<mydoc>
<canonical>my canonical stuff</canonical>
<original>my original stuff</original>
</mydoc>
```

then

```
xdmp:node-replace (
    fn:doc ('/mydoc.xml')/mydoc/original,
    <original>my new original stuff</original>
)
```

changes the store document to

```
<mydoc>
<canonical>my canonical stuff</canonical>
<original>my new original stuff</original>
</mydoc>
```